# Showing custom UIView when UIMenuItem is clicked

Tags: ios, uitextview, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

So I've created a custom view which I want to be displayed at the bottom of the screen to when a UIMenuItem is clicked.

I have in my ViewController.m :

```
UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
UIMenuItem *translateItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Translate" action:@selector(translateClicked:)];
[menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:translateItem]];
```

The UITextView concerned has a custom UITextView with the methods (CustomTextView.m):

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
if (action == @selector(copy:)) return YES;
if (action == @selector(translateClicked:)) return YES;
return NO;
}

- (IBAction)translateClicked:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"In Custom UITextView");
}
```

This shows "Copy" and "Translate" as the two menu options. Currently when "Translate" is clicked I get the log "In Custom UITextView".

Is it possible to  have a method within the ViewController.m to have the following code?

```
CustomPopUp *customView = [CustomPopUp customView];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself:

by removing the line:

```
if (action == @selector(translateClicked:)) return YES;
```

in CustomTextView.m

and adding:

```
- (void) translateClicked: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"In ViewController");
}
```

in ViewController.m. This allowed me to run methods within the original UIViewController.